# jQuery var not entering function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need an element to toggle when I press ***menu-toggle***, then when I press anywhere on the page (on the ***wrapper*** element), I need it to toggle again.

This is my code:

```
var bodyclick = 0;
console.log(bodyclick);

//If you clicks the menu toggle, then activate toggle and bodyclick should be 1
$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    bodyclick = 1;
    console.log(bodyclick);
});

//Now, that the bodyclick is 1, user should click anywhere on the wrapper to activate the toggle again
if (bodyclick === 1) {
    console.log("The wrapper is toggled");
    $("#wrapper").click(function(e) {
        //e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
        bodyclick = 0;
    });
}
```

When the user clicks on the ***#menu-toggle*** element, the wrapper should toggle and the bodyclick var should be 1.

Now the second function should work. If the user clicks ANYWHERE on the ***#wrapper***, it should toggle it again and change the bodyclick back to 0.

This is not working for some reason. It won't start the if statement. The console log shows bodyclick is 1, but the if is not working.

I tried using == but it doesn't change anything. Why isn't the if working?

**EDIT**
After adding @Nikhil Aggarwal answer:

```
var bodyclick = 0;
console.log(bodyclick);


$("#menu-toggle").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    bodyclick = 1;
    console.log(bodyclick);
});

$("#wrapper").click(function(e) {
    if (bodyclick === 1) {
        console.log("The wrapper is toggled");
       //e.preventDefault();
       $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
       bodyclick = 0; 
    }
});
```

The toggle works on #menu-toggle, it even sets the *bodyclick* to 1.

But when I click anywhere on the wrapper now (after the toggle on #menu-toggle), it won't toggle the element or change the bodyclick value back to zero.

I apologize for this but I just don't see the logic.

**FIXED**, thanks to @Nikhil Aggarwal:
Just needed to add the `e.stopPropagation();` in the *#menu-toggle* function.

Comment: Move `if (bodyclick === 1)` inside the event handler

Comment: jQuery does not proxies its variables and functions. bodyclick variable is only available while your DOM execution is finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your code to following

```
$("#wrapper").click(function(e) {
    if (bodyclick === 1) {
        console.log("The wrapper is toggled");
       //e.preventDefault();
       $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
       bodyclick = 0; 
    }
});
```

**Reason** - At the time of load, value of `bodyclick` was 0, hence, the if condition was never executed which also means the binding never happened. Hence, you should move the condition inside the event handler so that event handler exists at the time of load and is executed conditionally as required.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, and I fixed that. But I still do not get the result I want. The #menu-toggle works fine, but the #wrapper if doesn't work. I have updated my result with your answer.

Comment: @IkePr -  In your edit, you have added an extra var in this line`var bodyclick = 1;` which causes the problem. It should be simply `bodyclick = 1;`

Comment: That doesn't fix the problem unfortunately. Here is the entire code if it helps: https://jsfiddle.net/prozik/n12o3vhz/3/

Comment: @IkePr - Your fiddle did not load properly. Here is a working version - https://jsfiddle.net/3hy7Lwk2/

Comment: @IkePr  - Here is the fixed version of your example - https://jsfiddle.net/n12o3vhz/4/. You need to add `e.stopPropagation();` in your `$("#menu-toggle").click` function. As wrapper is parent of this, the click event bubbled and both click events were firing simultaneously which meant as soon as the bodyclick was set  to 1 it was set to 0 too because of this.

Answer (score 1):

You should refactor your code this way, because your previous code only fires once, and doesn't listen to click event:

```
$("#wrapper").click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   if (bodyclick === 1) {
       $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
       bodyclick = 0; 
   }
});
```